# searchByEmail method not working

Tags: java, search, hashmap

I have a problem with this method.  It does not output the correct search when the user asks for it.

Here is my code:

```
System.out.println("Search by Email.");
Employee employeeSearchEmail = MenuMethods.userInputByEmail();
Store.searchByEmail(employeeSearchEmail.getEmployeeEmail());

public Employee searchByEmail(String employeeEmail) {
    for (Employee employee : map.values()) {
        System.out.println(employee);
        map.equals(getClass());
        map.equals(employee.getEmployeeEmail());
        employee = new Employee(employeeEmail);
        ;
        return employee;
    }
    return null;
}

public static Employee userInputByEmail() {
    // String temp is for some reason needed. If it is not included
    // The code will not execute properly.
    String temp = keyboard.nextLine();
    Employee e = null;
    System.out.println("Please enter the Employee Email:");
    String employeeEmail = keyboard.nextLine();
    // This can use the employeeName's constructor because java accepts the
    // parameters instead
    // of the name's.
    return e = new Employee(employeeEmail);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is that there is no if condition in your program like this :

```
public Employee searchByEmail(String employeeEmail) {
        for (Employee employee : map.values()) {
            map.equals(getClass());
            if (map.equals(employee.getEmployeeEmail())){
                System.out.println(employee);
                return employee;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

this line :
    System.out.println(employee);

it will print employee object until it finds the match and when match it will return that employee object..

Comment: When i do that it prints out the whole store.

Comment: whole store means all employee data

Comment: Well yes, All of the employees.

Comment: until it finds the appropriate match not after that??

Comment: if so then its because of System.out.println(employee); it will print until it finds the match and when match it will return that employee object..

Comment: What would be my solution to this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14216/discussion-between-blackpanther-and-pendo826)

Answer (score 0):

You should say like this

```
if(employeeEmail.equals(employee.getEmployeeEmail()) return employee;
```

There is no need of creating a new instance of `Employee` object.

Answer (score 0):

You want to return an employee with a specific email address. So you should only return if the email address of the current employee equals the given email address:

```
 public Employee searchByEmail(String employeeEmail) 
    {
            for(Employee employee : map.values())
            {
                if(employee.getEmployeeEmail().equalsIgnoreCase(employeeEmail.trim()))
                          return employee;
            }
            return null;
    }
```

By the way, what are the keys of the map. In case the email addresses are the keys you can simply return:

```
   return map.get(employeeEmail);
```

Comment: im getting an error on the if statement line of your code.

Comment: Nope name is the key.  email and id are inherited from the employee class.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at EmployeeStore.searchByEmail(EmployeeStore.java:83)
 at MainApp.start(MainApp.java:115)
 at MainApp.main(MainApp.java:12)

Comment: The String you are passing as an argument to searchEmail is null or the current employee is null.
Try debugging or at least try printing the employeeEmail.

Comment: Ive been trying all of that and i just cant figure it out.